# Como concatenar valor em um dropdownlist no laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5

Como adicionar o primeiro valor padrão em uma dropdownlist? Tentei fazer desta forma:

```
{!! Form::select('Usuario.est_id',array('null' => 'Selecione') + $estados, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

mas me retorna o erro:
FatalErrorException in 30aae33d562adffd11ade38d9100e329 line 26:
Unsupported operand types

Os $estados são uma collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

faz assim

```
{!! Form::select('Usuario.est_id',array_merge(['null' => 'Selecione'],
       Estado::orderBy('uf')->lists('uf', 'est_id')), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: Não funcionou ele me retorna array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array (View: C:\wamp\www\cristiana\resources\views\usuarios\index.blade.php)

Comment: teu segundo argumento não é arrau, então tu faz $estado->toArray();